# Expectation of a hazard rate

Tags: distributions, expected-value, gamma-distribution, hazard, proportional-hazards

I need to estimate the expectation of a hazard function, $E[h(x)]$.  For instance,  for the exponential distribution  the result is equal $\lambda$

$$E[h(x)] = \int_0^\infty \! h(x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty \! \lambda \cdot \lambda exp(-\lambda x) \, \mathrm{d}x=\lambda. $$

But I am not sure how we can generalized this result for other probability distribution functions with positive support. For instance, Burr distribution or the Generalized gamma distribution. I will use this result in the context of autoregressive conditional duration models.
 Do you know if there exists some general result for this question?

Comment: Your integration is not correct; $$\int_{x=0}^\infty \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda x} \, dx = \lambda,$$ not $1$.

Comment: Thanks heropup, I will change the question. But what about other distributions?

Comment: What kind of generalization are you looking for?  An exponential distribution is a very special case in which the hazard rate is constant, so the expected value of the hazard rate is that constant.

Comment: One thing we can say without much effort is that if $X$ belongs to a location-scale family, the expectation of its hazard function is invariant with respect to the location parameter, and it is inversely proportional to the scale parameter.  But in general, many common parametric distributions would not have closed-form solutions for the expectation of the hazard function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can generalize the integration to get a concept for finding $E[h(x)]$ since that depends on the distribution function and also $h(x)$ can be a constant or a function based on the distribution of $x$. 
What kind of generalization you are looking for.

Comment: $h$ is always a function--it might have a constant *value*.